# Displaying Media from Memory stream

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

So I want to take a video which I stored in a random access memory stream in and re display this video onto a `CaptureUIElement`.  I am programming a Windows Store APP in C#.

Here is the code that writes to the random access stream.

```
sentvideo.StartRecordToStreamAsync(encodingprofile, memorystream);
```

Now I want to read from the memomry stream and display the media to the uicaptureelement.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the StartPreviewAsync() API for this.

Have you seen this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868171.aspx. The link explains how you can preview video from a camera or a webcam.

Comment: I already know how to use the preview API.  The preview API reads directly from the webcam not the memeory stream.  What I need to know is how to play a video from a memory stream.  I've had mild success using the mediaelement API, but it will only play the first frame of the video